# Python finding the a player with the most "wins" in a list

Tags: python, list

I need some help trying to figure out a quick algorithm that I am struggling to write. Basically I have a list that looks like:

```
season = [[['P1', '3', 'P2', '4'], ['P3', '2', 'P4', '1'], 
           ['P1', '2', 'P3', '5'], ['P4', '2', 'P1', '3']]]
```

Each nested list represents a score in a game between players and the list has a lot more nested lists that follow the same format as shown above and the players go up to 32.

What I am trying to do is write an algorithm that will allow me to display the player who has the most wins in the list as well as, the amount of wins they have achieved and I am struggling to figure out how to do this, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Below is what I have so far:

```
count = 0
for matchScores in season:
    for scores in matchScores:
        playerName = score[0]
        if playerName and score[1] > score[3]
            count = count + 1
```

The list 'season' was created by:

```
season = []
season.append(tournament1)
season.append(tournament2)
season.append(tournament3)
```

etc

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: Let us also see what have you done so far!

Comment: Also please explain why you have a list of lists of lists, but the second-most inner list only has one element, a list of scores. Why don't you just have a list of lists?

Comment: It is largely due to how the list was created, the scores in each list have all come from a variety of different lists and have been stored into one list, I will edit my original post to show how the list was created

Comment: Use a `dict` to keep track of the numbers of wins per player as you iterate through all matches. Hint: `n_wins = defaultdict(int)` (from `collections`),  within loop + logic: `n_wins[winner] += 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

**Code**

```
scores = dict()

for match in season:
  for score in match:
    if int(score[1]) > int(score[3]):
      if score[0] not in scores:
        scores[score[0]] = 0

      scores[score[0]] += 1

    elif int(score[1]) < int(score[3]):
      if score[2] not in scores:
        scores[score[2]] = 0

      scores[score[2]] += 1

print(scores)
```

**Result**

```
{'P2': 1, 'P3': 2, 'P1': 1}
```

This will give you a dictionary of all players and their scores. From there, you could do something like this

```
player_with_most_wins = max(scores, key=scores.get) 
print(player_with_most_wins + " has " + str(scores[player_with_most_wins]) + " wins")
```

to print out the player with the most wins, and how many wins they have as follows:

```
P3 has 2 wins
```

Comment: Fantastic, that's exactly what I was attempting to do! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to associate the win with each player:

#### Code:

```
season = [[['P1', '3', 'P2', '4'], ['P3', '2', 'P4', '1'],
           ['P1', '2', 'P3', '5'], ['P4', '2', 'P1', '3']]]


wins = {}
for matchScores in season:
    for score in matchScores:
        p1, s1, p2, s2 = score
        s1, s2 = int(s1), int(s2)
        if s1 > s2:
            wins.setdefault(p1, []).append(score)
        elif s1 < s2:
            wins.setdefault(p2, []).append(score)

print(wins)
```

#### Results:

```
{
    'P2': [['P1', '3', 'P2', '4']], 
    'P3': [['P3', '2', 'P4', '1'], ['P1', '2', 'P3', '5']], 
    'P1': [['P4', '2', 'P1', '3']]    
}
```